# Unable to download base64 encoded image on Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, base64, url-encoding

I have an app that, when clicking on a link, opens a new window with the following code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,...">
    </body>
</html>
```

On Chrome, if I right-click and select `Save image as...` option, the pop up to select saving location does not appear.

At the beginning I thought it was a Chrome error, but to test it I have copied the same code on a separate html page and I am able to download it.

So, anyone has a clue for what can be happening here?

Comment: So many years past, still the same.